# Can I say “perspective into something”?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

For example "That's an unusual perspective into how it works.", meaning a point of view, an understanding of it.

Maybe some other preposition instead of "into"?

Comment: By far the most common preposition after ***perspective*** is ***on***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "on"
so ""That's an unusual perspective **on** how it works."

On is the most common preposition used after perspective